# 403 Forbidden on nginx/1.8.0 (Fedora 22 - Laravel 5.1)

Tags: php, apache, nginx, laravel-5.1, fedora

I keep getting `403 Forbidden`

my settings file `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`

```
   server {
      listen       80 default_server;
     listen       [::]:80 default_server;
     server_name  _;
     #root         /usr/share/nginx/html;
     root         /var/www/nginx/html;

    # Load configuration files for the default server block.
    include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;


    location / {
       }

    error_page 404 /404.html;
        location = /40x.html {
    }

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
    }
  }
}
```

Note: i have all permissions on my `root dir` and the same app working well with `Apache` server

**Updates**

Now i have solved the issue by install `php-fpm` **but now when go to laravel app laravel route redirect me to the home page in my app is** `/auth/login`

**but Nginx geeting** `The page you are looking for is not found.`

Any Help?